# Increasing faces using brush

Tags: sculpting

Watching a tutorial, the artist used a brush to increase the geometry (faces/polygons) by turning the brush strength to zero and moving it over the mesh.
I can not locate this part. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried doing this yourself? What happened? It sounds like they had Dynamic Topology  enabled, which you should make sure you also have enabled (either on the top bar or in the tools panel).

Comment: That was it. I used a brush, turned strength to 0 and turned on DT. It added more geometry to a very segmented stl file.
Thank you.

Comment: Ok great. I added an answer that you can accept just in case anyone else has the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

To do this, enable dynamic topology in sculpting mode, which will increase the subdivison level based on the dyntopo settings on whatever section you are sculpting on. Then, if you set the brush strength to zero, it will increase the topology while having no additional effect.